# how to display product image in order history in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I need to display product image in order details page when user click order details link.

I have edited below code in order-detail.tpl but it not shows product image it shows only some dummy image

```
<td> 
<a href="{$link->getProductLink($product.product_id, $product.link_rewrite, $product.category, null, null, $product.id_shop, $product.id_product_attribute)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
<img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'small_default')}" alt="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($smallSize)}width="{$smallSize.width}" height="{$smallSize.height}" {/if} /></a>

</td>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that page you can view the variable what comes with $product. Like this.

```
    {$product|var_dump}
```

and you will notice that $product have a array value image which is a object

so now go with this.

```
    {$product.image|var_dump}
```

and you will view all this value.

> ```
>                     object(Image)#490 (26) {
>   ["id"]=&gt;
>   int(1)
>   ["id_image"]=&gt;
>   string(1) "1"
>   ["id_product"]=&gt;
>   string(1) "3"
>   ["position"]=&gt;
>   string(1) "1"
>   ["cover"]=&gt;
>   string(1) "1"
>   ["image_format"]=&gt;
>   string(3) "jpg"
>   ["source_index"]=&gt;
>   string(52) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prestashop/img/p/index.php"
>   ["folder":protected]=&gt;
>   NULL
>   ["existing_path":protected]=&gt;
>   NULL
>   ["id_lang":protected]=&gt;
>   NULL
>   ["id_shop":protected]=&gt;
>   int(1)
>   ["id_shop_list"]=&gt;
>   NULL
>   ["get_shop_from_context":protected]=&gt;
>   bool(true)
>   ["table":protected]=&gt;
>   string(5) "image"
>   ["identifier":protected]=&gt;
>   string(8) "id_image"
>   ["fieldsRequired":protected]=&gt;
>   array(1) {
>     [0]=&gt;
>     string(10) "id_product"
>   }
>   ["fieldsSize":protected]=&gt;
>   array(0) {
>   }
>   ["fieldsValidate":protected]=&gt;
>   array(3) {
>     ["id_product"]=&gt;
>     string(12) "isUnsignedId"
>     ["position"]=&gt;
>     string(13) "isUnsignedInt"
>     ["cover"]=&gt;
>     string(6) "isBool"
>   }
>   ["fieldsRequiredLang":protected]=&gt;
>   array(0) {
>   }
>   ["fieldsSizeLang":protected]=&gt;
>   array(0) {
>   }
>   ["fieldsValidateLang":protected]=&gt;
>   array(0) {
>   }
>   ["tables":protected]=&gt;
>   array(0) {
>   }
>   ["webserviceParameters":protected]=&gt;
>   array(0) {
>   }
>   ["image_dir":protected]=&gt;
>   string(43) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/prestashop/img/p/"
>   ["def":protected]=&gt;
>   array(6) {
>     ["table"]=&gt;
>     string(5) "image"
>     ["primary"]=&gt;
>     string(8) "id_image"
>     ["multilang"]=&gt;
>     bool(true)
>     ["fields"]=&gt;
>     array(3) {
>       ["id_product"]=&gt;
>       array(3) {
>         ["type"]=&gt;
>         int(1)
>         ["validate"]=&gt;
>         string(12) "isUnsignedId"
>         ["required"]=&gt;
>         bool(true)
>       }
>       ["position"]=&gt;
>       array(2) {
>         ["type"]=&gt;
>         int(1)
>         ["validate"]=&gt;
>         string(13) "isUnsignedInt"
>       }
>       ["cover"]=&gt;
>       array(3) {
>         ["type"]=&gt;
>         int(2)
>         ["validate"]=&gt;
>         string(6) "isBool"
>         ["shop"]=&gt;
>         bool(true)
>       }
>     }
>     ["classname"]=&gt;
>     string(5) "Image"
>     ["associations"]=&gt;
>     array(1) {
>       ["l"]=&gt;
>       array(3) {
>         ["type"]=&gt;
>         int(2)
>         ["field"]=&gt;
>         string(8) "id_image"
>         ["foreign_field"]=&gt;
>         string(8) "id_image"
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   ["update_fields":protected]=&gt;
>   NULL
> }
> ```

```
                                                                                                                You will notice that there is not value of link_rewrite. So you need to pass that from the controller.
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to do this in PS 1.3 version, and I have problem too :/ When I display  {$product.image|var_dump} variable I get NULL

Function getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'small_default') working good, but the problem is to get values from variables $product.link_rewrite and $product.id_image but I unfortunately don't know how to.

Now they are empty and so on links to image is incorrect